# GCP IAM: Binding role to Service Account fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I have created a `ServiceAccount` and a custom role from the GCP console.

However when trying to associate them, it fails as below:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project \
  --member serviceAccount:cloudrun-poc@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --role roles/MyCustomRole
ERROR: Policy modification failed. For a binding with condition, run "gcloud alpha iam policies lint-condition" to identify issues in condition.
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Role roles/ClusterUpscaler is not supported for this resource.
```

any ideas why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have to [create](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#creating_a_custom_role) role `MyCustomRole` before attempting to assign it. No clue what it complains about role `ClusterUpscaler`, but there might not be a cluster present in that project... besides custom roles usually have names alike `projects/{project-id}/roles/{role-name}`. They can also be listed:

```
gcloud iam list-grantable-roles //cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/PROJECT_ID
```

Comment: `ClusterUpscaler` is a custom role with just this permission: `container.clusters.update`. I am trying to create a CloudRun service that should be able to invoke the `gcloud container clusters update` command. Any other suggestions are more than welcome

Comment: btw the role is listed when I use the command you posted above

Comment: @pkaramol custom roles are always per project, you might need to fully qualified name to assign it (opposite to the pre-defined roles, which are available globally).

Comment: wow! that was it! it just needed the fq role name! such a misleading error message...anyway I suggest you update your answer accordingly so that I accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You could run `gcloud alpha iam policies lint-condition` as the output suggests. For me, it was a missing gcloud command "Alpha".