# How to add GCP role to the grantable list?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, roles

I am trying to get a service account set up in GCP so I can use

docker pull

from my personal shell as well as from Google Cloud Shell, where it works automagically.

I tried this:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding myProject --member=serviceAccount:dockerdude --role=roles/container.admin
```

But I got this not-very-helpful error:

ERROR: Policy modification failed. For a binding with condition, run "gcloud alpha iam policies lint-condition" to identify issues in condition.
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid service account (dockerdude).

I found the problem: this role isn't **grantable** ... I used the command

```
gcloud iam list-grantable-roles 
         //cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/myProject
```

... and indeed the role **container.admin** isn't in the list.

My question: how do I make this role **grantable**? Or is there some other way to get what I'm looking for (**docker pull** permission from user shells as well as from Google Cloud Shell)?

Thanks much for any insight into this problem whatsoever!

Comment: What is **dockerdude**? The error message says **Invalid service account**. IAM members use the email address format.

Comment: The container.admin is grantable at the project level. However, the service account is in the bad format. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#kubernetes-engine-roles

Comment: I got it using the dockerdude@email  syntax to get the service acccount hooked to the container.admin role. I guess it *was* grantable after all and I just missed it. Thanks.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful for you or the community you could consider upvoting/accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this reference to write your command interactively, [Granting a Single Role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/manage-access-service-accounts#grant-single-role):

> **Note**: If you want to identify a service account just after it is created, use the numeric ID rather than the email address to ensure that it is reliably identified.

```sh
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding ServiceAccount_ID \
    --member=PRINCIPAL --role=ROLE_ID \
    --condition=CONDITION
```

Some missing parameters, but should be…

```sh
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --member=serviceAccount:duckerdude@example.com --role=/roles/container.clusterAdmin
```

Also check this very good [explanation of the service accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61878052/16938011) as they can be described as an identity and a resource, check the full question to get more details:

> You have to read the command like this
>
> ```
> gcloud <resourceType> add-iam-policy-binding <resourceName> --member=<accountToGrantOnTheResource> --role=<roleToGrantOnTheResource>
> ```

Additionally, read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58086594/16938011) related to `list-grantable-roles` command:

> They can also be listed:
>
> ```
> gcloud iam list-grantable-roles //cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/PROJECT_ID
> ```